# Bluetooth adapter problem

Tags: bluetooth

the  Bluetooth adapter is not working in Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop ,
i want to use my headset with my desktop , i try to fix by this methods but it is not working

1. install bluez but not working 
   2-  start the Bluetooth command 
   by **systemctl enable bluetooth.service** still it is not working 
   3- rest the BIOS
   the output for some commands

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:339a]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**cie@cie-HP-Compaq-Pro-6300-MT:~$ lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

Can any one help how can i fix  this problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: cie@cie-HP-Compaq-Pro-6300-MT:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
 DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:339a]
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e
 Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)

Comment: cie@cie-HP-Compaq-Pro-6300-MT:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please EDIT !!!!YOUR QUESTION!!!! Do not post it to comments !!! Can you read?

Comment: Is it an external USB adapter?

Comment: no there is no external usb

Comment: So what is you BT adapter? Is it built in to your desktop? Are you sure you have a BT adapter?

Comment: i don't think  the built in  bt adapter is not working  ,does i need external bt  adapter ???

Comment: How do you know you have ANY BT adapter?

Comment: b/c the bt was working when i use window  it stop when i turn to Ubuntu

Comment: This is more clear. Then add the output of `lspci` to your question. Let's look for it.

Comment: I do not see any bluetooth devices in the system. Desktop computers rarely have BT adapters.